# My discord bot is online but doesn't interact

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py, bots

I came back to creating bots on discord, but this time with Python, it seems I am doing something wrong, and I don't know what it is.

I placed a simple code, which is (command-reply), but the bot does not answer and does nothing about it.

My bot is *online*, I don't get *errors* in my terminal, and I am using the correct *token*.

Here is my code:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello there!")

client.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't enable the [`message_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) intent.

Docs about intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: I feel so stupid xD thank you